# Chebyshev’s Inequality with gaussian distribution random variable

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

Chebyshev's inequality is:

$\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$

When we have gaussian distribution random variable it change to:

$\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq e^{-k^2}$

How can prof the result of gaussian random variable for Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Chebyshev works for all random variables. When you know explicitly the law of the random variable, it is possible to compute the tail probabilities with a lot more accuracy

Comment: @tortue I want know how $1/{k^2}$ convert to $e^{-k^2}$ for  gaussian random variables.